# Is there any option to disable follow redirect on Microprofile REST Client

Tags: java, rest-client, quarkus, microprofile

I need disable follow redirect on REST Clinet in Microprofile(Quarkus). Is there any configuration option to change this behavior?

Regards,
Łukasz

Comment: From all indications, there isn't a reliable way to just configure it on the client per JAX-RS spec. All that's left to do is for you to manually take control of the situation with a `ClientRequestFilter`. In the filter, you'll watch for 302 redirects and ignore them. Make sense?